# Consolibyte QuickBooks PHP Library - Importing All Active Customers

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I am looking at the directory of example files at https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/web_connector for Consolibyte's QuickBooks PHP library and don't see an example that allows you to import a list of all customers in your QuickBooks instance.

Is there an example for this?  If not, what would the XML look like?  I am looking to import all active customers in my QB installation; every customer that I see here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the example functions in the `example_web_connector_import.php` file under `/docs/web_connector`.  The specific methods were `_quickbooks_customer_import_request()` and `_quickbooks_customer_import_response()`